# Se não couber na div, mostrar: mais X resultados

Tags: php, html, css, oracle

Preciso resolver o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma div que apresenta uma lista de nomes que são carregados conforme uma condição de consulta.

Essa lista de nomes varia muito, as vezes aparece 5, outras vezes aparece 30 nomes.

Preciso que seja limitado a visualização dos nomes da seguinte forma, apareça os nomes até o final da DIV e no final apareça um contador dos que faltam. Por exemplo, ao invez de aparecer NOME1,NOME2,NOME3,NOME4,NOME5 em uma DIV que cabe apenas 3 nomes, apareça, NOME1,NOME2,EXISTEM MAIS 3 NOMES.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Hoje estou mostrando os nomes na tela com a consulta abaixo, porém, as vezes ocorre o problema citado.

```
    <?php
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($nomes, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
        $NOME   = $row['NOME'];

        <div id="linhaazul"> 
            <div id="celpaciente"><b><?echo $NOME ?></b></div>                      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom realmente, com os itens sendo renderizados pelo `PHP` fica um pouco difícil e qualquer solução irá soar como uma gambiarra, mas vamos lá.

Você pode usar a propriedade `text-overflow` do `CSS`, que basicamente, identifica se um determinado texto ultrapassou os limites do container e adiciona um texto correspondente, exemplo...

Em uma `div` com 200px e um texto que ultrapassa esses 200px

```css
div#teste {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ' E mais...';
}
```

```html
<div id="teste">
Teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste teste
</div>
```

(caso não atinja o limite, a string ' E mais...' não é adicionado)

Só ai já estava de bom tamanho, porém se é um requisito muito importante contar quantos faltaram, você pode fazer o seguinte...

Troque o `text-overflow` de ' E mais...' para ' Mais XX nomes';

Ao realizar o looping nos resultados, armazene a quantidade de nomes em uma variável `javascript` exemplo...

```
let totalNomes = <?= $total ?> // 30 nomes
```

Após isso pegue o texto da `div`, e verifique com uma expressão regular ou outro método se existe a palavra " Mais XX nomes", se existir é por que o texto extrapolou a `div`, então é só pegar esse texto, tirando a string ' Mais XX nomes', dar um `split` nas `virgulas` e verificar o `length`, o resultado vai ser a quantidade de nomes que entrou na `div`.

Ai é só subtrair esse resultado com o total de nomes que vai dar a quantidade que falta na `div`, após isso é só setar na `div` um novo text overflow substituindo o ' Mais XX nomes', pelo valor resultante ' Mais '+result+' nomes';

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável que te diga quantos itens tem o seu array de resultado e uma outra variável para te indicar quantos itens você já mostrou na tela. Quando for iterar para mostrar os nomes use um if para mostrar apenas enquanto a quantidade de itens mostrados na tela for menor que dois. Caso seja maior, subtraia 2 do valor total.
Vai ficar algo do tipo

```
 var quantidadeLinhasNoResultado
 var quantidadeLinhasInseridas

 for iterando no resultado
      if( quantidadeLinhasInseridas < 2)
           mostra o nome
           incrementa quantidadeLinhasInseridas em mais um
      else
           mostra " e mais " (quantidadeLinhasNoResultado - 2) " nomes"
           Sai do for.
```

Claro, vais ter que mudar essa parte em "pseudo código" para php, mas a ideia geral é essa.